# Use of ddply + mutate with a custom function?

Tags: r, plyr

I use `ddply` quite frequently, but historically with `summarize` (occasionally `mutate`) and only basic functions like `mean()`, `var1 - var2`, etc. I have a dataset in which I'm trying to apply a custom, more involved function and started trying to dig into how to do this with `ddply`. I've got a successful solution, but I don't understand *why* it works like this vs. for more "normal" functions.

**Related**

- [Custom Function not recognized by ddply {plyr}...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556877/custom-function-not-recognized-by-ddply-plyr-it-tells-me-that-my-function-is)
- [How do I pass variables to a custom function in ddply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845409/how-do-i-pass-variables-to-a-custom-function-in-ddply)
- [r-help: [R] Correct use of ddply with own function](http://grokbase.com/t/r/r-help/1255y8qvty/r-correct-use-of-ddply-with-own-function) (I ended up basing my solution on this)

Here's an example data set:

```
library(plyr)
df <- data.frame(id = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3),
                 value = 1:9)
```

Normally, I'd use `ddply` like so:

```
df_ply_1 <- ddply(df, .(id), mutate, mean = mean(value))
```

My visualization of this is that `ddply` splits `df` into "mini" data frames based on grouped combos of `id`, and then I add a new column by calling `mean()` on a column name that exists in `df`. So, my attempt to implement a function extended this idea:

```
# actually, my logical extension of the above was to use:
# ddply(..., mean = function(value) { mean(value) })
df_ply_2 <- ddply(df, .(id), mutate,
                  mean = function(df) { mean(df$value) })

Error: attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'
```

All the help on custom functions don't apply `mutate`, but that seems inconsistent, or at least annoying to me, as the analog to my implemented solution is:

```
df_mean <- function(df) {
    temp <- data.frame(mean = rep(mean(df$value), nrow(df)))
    temp
}

df_ply_3 <- df
df_ply_3$mean <- ddply(df, .(id), df_mean)$mean
```

In-line, looks like I have to do this:

```
df_ply_4 <- df
df_ply_4$mean <- ddply(df, .(id), function(x) {
    temp <- data.frame(mean = rep(mean(x$value), length(x$value)))
    temp})$mean
```

Why can't I use `mutate` with a custom function? Is it just that "built-in" functions return some sort of class that `ddply` can deal with vs. having to kick out a full `data.frame` and then call out only the column I care about?

Thanks for helping me "get it"!

---

**Update after @Gregor's answer**

Awesome answer, and I think I now get it. I was, indeed, confused about what `mutate` and `summarize` meant... thinking they were arguments to `ddply` regarding how to handle the result vs. actually *being* the functions themselves. So, thanks for that big insight.

Also, it really helped to understand that *without* `mutate/summarize`, I need to return a `data.frame`, which is the reason I have to `cbind` a column with the name of the column in the `df` that gets returned.

Lastly if I *do* use `mutate`, it's helpful to now realize I can return a vector result and get the right result. Thus, I *can* do this, which I've now understood after reading your answer:

```
# I also caught that the code above doesn't do the right thing
# and recycles the single value returned by mean() vs. repeating it like
# I expected. Now that I know it's taking a vector, I know I need to return
# a vector the same length as my mini df
custom_mean <- function(x) {
    rep(mean(x), length(x))
}

df_ply_5 <- ddply(df, .(id), mutate,
              mean = custom_mean(value))
```

Thanks again for your in-depth answer!

---

**Update per @Gregor's last comment**

Hmmm. I used `rep(mean(x), length(x))` due to this observation for `df_ply_3`'s result (I admit to not actually looking at it closely when I ran it the first time making this post, I just saw that it didn't give me an error!):

```
df_mean <- function(x) {
    data.frame(mean = mean(x$value))
}

df_ply_3 <- df
df_ply_3$mean <- ddply(df, .(id), df_mean)$mean

df_ply_3
  id value mean
1  a     1    2
2  a     2    5
3  a     3    8
4  b     4    2
5  b     5    5
6  b     6    8
7  c     7    2
8  c     8    5
9  c     9    8
```

So, I'm thinking that my code was actually an accident based on the fact that I had 3 `id` variables repeated 3 times. Thus the actual return was the equivalent of `summarize` (one row per `id` value), and recycled. Testing that theory appears accurate if I update my data frame like so:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(rep(letters[1:3], each = 3), "d"),
                 value = 1:10)
```

I get an error when trying to use the `df_ply_3` method with `df_mean()`:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "mean", value = c(2, 5, 8, 10)) : 
  replacement has 4 rows, data has 10
```

So, the mini df passed to `df_mean` returns a `df` where `mean` is the result of taking the mean if the `value` vector (returns one value). So, my output was just a `data.frame` of three values, one per `id` group. I'm thinking the `mutate` way sort of "remembers" that it was passed a mini data frame, and then repeats the single output to match it's length?

In any case, thanks for commenting on `df_ply_5`; indeed, if I remove the `rep()` bit and just return `mean(x)`, it works great!

Comment: maybe you want `ddply(df, .(id), function(d) mutate(d, mean = mean(value)))`

Comment: Looks like you've got it pretty well! But regarding your `custom_mean` function... thanks to recycling if you want the same value multiple times you *can* just return one value, it's a nice feature! Notice that your `df_ply_1`, your `df_ply_5` and @baptiste's comment code are all slightly different, but the returns are all the same.

Comment: @Gregor Updated with another section based on your comment. Yup, that works and now I think I get why.

Comment: @baptiste Awesome! Now that I Understand that `mutate` actually *is* the function passed to `ddply()` (vs. my thought that it was some argument telling `ddply()` how to return the result), it makes sense that I could call it like that *as the function* vs. trying to specify an additional function to "mutate on."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're mostly right. `ddply` indeed breaks your data down into mini data frames based on the grouper, and applies a function to each piece.

With `ddply`, all the work is done with data frames, so the `.fun` argument **must** take a (mini) data frame as input and return a data frame as output.

`mutate` and `summarize` are functions that fit this bill (they take and return data frames). You can view their individual help pages, or run them on a data frame outside of `ddply` to see this, e.g.

```
mutate(mtcars, mean.mpg = mean(mpg))
summarize(mtcars, mean.mpg = mean(mpg))
```

If you *don't* use `mutate` or `summarize`, that is, you **only** use a custom function, then your function also needs to take a (mini) data frame as argument, and return a data frame.

If you **do** use `mutate` or `summarize`, any other functions you pass to `ddply` aren't used by `ddply`, they're just passed on to be used by `mutate` or `summarize`. And functions used by `mutate` and `summarize` act on the columns of the data, not on the entire data.frame. This is why

```
ddply(mtcars, "cyl", mutate, mean.mpg = mean(mpg))
```

Notice that we don't pass `mutate` a function. We don't say `ddply(mtcars, "cyl", mutate, mean)`. We have to tell it what to take the mean of. In `?mutate`, the description of `...` is "named parameters giving definitions of new columns", not anything to do with functions. (Is `mean()` really different from any "custom function"? No.)

Thus it doesn't work with anonymous functions--or functions at all. Pass it an expression! You can define a custom function beforehand.

```
custom_function <- function(x) {mean(x + runif(length(x))}
ddply(mtcars, "cyl", mutate, jittered.mean.mpg = custom_function(mpg))
ddply(mtcars, "cyl", summarize, jittered.mean.mpg = custom_function(mpg))
```

This extends well, you can have functions that take multiple arguments, and you can give them different columns as arguments, but if you're using the `mutate` or `summarize`, you have to give the other functions arguments; you're not just passing the functions.

You seem to want to pass `ddply` a function that already "knows" which column to take the mean of. For that, I think you'd need to *not* use `mutate` or `summarize`, but you can hack your own version. For `summarize`-like behavior, return a data.frame with a single value, for `mutate`-like behavior, return the original data.frame with your extra value `cbind`ed on

```
mean.mpg.mutate = function(df) {
    cbind.data.frame(df, mean.mpg = mean(df$mpg))
}

mean.mpg.summarize = function(df) {
    data.frame(mean.mpg = mean(df$mpg))
}

ddply(mtcars, "cyl", mean.mpg.mutate)
ddply(mtcars, "cyl", mean.mpg.summarize)
```

### tl;dr

> Why can't I use mutate with a custom function? Is it just that "built-in" functions return some sort of class that ddply can deal with vs. having to kick out a full data.frame and then call out only the column I care about?

Quite the opposite! `mutate` and `summarize` take data frames as inputs and kick out data frames as returns. But *mutate and summarize **are** the functions you're passing to ddply*, not mean or whatever else.

Mutate and summarize are convenience functions that you'll use 99% of the time you use `ddply`.

If you don't use mutate/summarize, then your function needs to take and return a data frame.

If you do use mutate/summarize, then you don't pass them functions, you pass them expressions that can be evaluated with your (mini) data frame. If it's mutate, the return should be a vector to be appended to the data (recycled as necessary). If it's summarize, the return should be a single value. You don't pass a function, like `mean`; you pass an expression, like `mean(mpg)`.

---

### What about `dplyr`?

This was written before `dplyr` was a thing, or at least a big thing. `dplyr` removes a lot of the confusion from this process because it essentially replaces the nesting of `ddply` with `mutate` or `summarize` as arguments with sequential functions `group_by` followed by `mutate` or `summarize`. The `dplyr` version of my answer would be

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(mtcars, cyl) %>%
    mutate(mean.mpg = mean(mpg))
```

With the new column creation passed directly to `mutate` (or `summarize`), there isn't confusion about which function does what.

Comment: The basic problem with the questioner's 'custom function' was that it was attempting to work on an object from the global environment that was "too big" for the multiple smaller local environments. Seems like the `mutate` function should be throwing a more informative error message.

Comment: I agree the error message was pretty unhelpful, there's plenty of cases where passing objects from the global environment (usually as extra arguments) to the function is exactly what is needed, so I don't see an obvious solution.

Comment: Maybe `mutate` should just produce the error message: "Don't send functions to me."

Comment: Awesome answer, and thanks so much for your assistance. I'm newer to functions, and think another issue was assuming that defining an "in-line" function would pick up the name of the mini data.frame (as in `mean = function(value) { mean(value) }` would pass `mini.df$value`, whereas it's just an anonymous thing called `value` that it's passing. Or at least I think that's what's going on. `mutate` doesn't find the thing called `value` and I'm assuming type `closure` means "doesn't exist." In any case, thanks again. This was perfect and will hopefully serve many others well!

Comment: Glad it helped! Your comment is incorrectly using "closure" and "anonymous function", the best source I know for that is [Hadley's Advanced R Book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html) (that link is to the Functional Programming Chapter, which has sections on both those terms).

Comment: @Gregor have I completely misunderstood the above or is it not possible to pass other objects to mutate other than the df in question. I.e. if I have a used defined function of the form MyFun(df, ob1, ob2), the following will not work df%>%rowwise()%>%mutate(X=MyFun(ob1,ob2)). Why?

Comment: In that chain you could probably just do `%>% mutate(., X = MyFun(., ob1, ob2))`. But the real question is why `MyFun` needs a data frame? If it is made for adding columns to data frames, then it should return the data frame with the added column and you don't need mutate: `%>% MyFun(ob1, ob2)`.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor I changed it to the latter, however I now get error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type double. I suspect it has to do with the way MyFun is written, i.e., it uses df[,"Col"] which the dplyr solution is taking to mean all rows, not row by row like when one uses apply(df,2,fun)

Comment: Agreed, it's probably how the function is written. Ask a new question if you're having trouble. That way you can show the function (or a simplified version).