# In ddply(), must custom function be defined before hand if I want to mutate a new column with that custom function?

Tags: r, plyr, anonymous-function

Let's say I have this sample dataframe:

```
df = data.frame(id=rep(1:2,each=5),v1=c(1:10),v2=c(1:10))
```

And, say, I would like to create a new column sumv1v2, that would contain the sum of v1 and v2, only if id = 1 (otherwise sumv1v2 would be 0) .

The following, with a custom function defined before hand, works:

```
condisum = function(pid,pv1,pv2){
  if (pid[1]==1) {pv1+pv2}
  else {0}
}
df = ddply(df,"id",mutate,sumv1v2=condisum(id,v1,v2))
```

And the returned dataframe is what I need:

```
df
   id v1 v2 sumv1v2
1   1  1  1       2
2   1  2  2       4
3   1  3  3       6
4   1  4  4       8
5   1  5  5      10
6   2  6  6       0
7   2  7  7       0
8   2  8  8       0
9   2  9  9       0
10  2 10 10       0
```

But could I define the function like inline within `ddply()`, i.e. like a anonymous  function? I tried this:

```
df = data.frame(id=rep(1:2,each=5),v1=c(1:10),v2=c(1:10))
df = ddply(df,"id",mutate,sumv1v2=function(pid,pv1,pv2){
  if (pid[1]==1) {pv1+pv2}
  else {0}
}(id,v1,v2))
```

And I got this error message:

```
Error: attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'
```

I know I cannot pass a function to `mutate`, and should pass an expression, thanks to the excellent comment by Gregor in this post:

[Use of ddply + mutate with a custom function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26935150/use-of-ddply-mutate-with-a-custom-function)

So I am trying to pass a anonymous function with argument to it. Would this make it an expression? But I still got an error.

So, is it possible NOT to define the custom function before hand, and define it with `function()` inside `ddply()`?

Answer (score 1):

Oh after more trial, I realize the issue, finally.

The following now works:

```
df = data.frame(id=rep(1:2,each=5),v1=c(1:10),v2=c(1:10))
df = ddply(df,"id",mutate,sumv1v2=(function(pid,pv1,pv2){
  if (pid[1]==1) {pv1+pv2}
  else {0}
})(id,v1,v2))
```

Take note of the new `(` and `)` around the anonymous function. Guess this turns it into a function at last, and with `(id,v1,v2)` to pass in the parameters, the whole thing finally becomes an expression.

In simpler form, I tried this:

```
x = function(y){y^2}(3)
x
```

and x returns:

```
function(y){y^2}(3)
```

But, if I add `(` and `)`:

```
x = (function(y) y^2)(3)
x
```

x returns:

```
[1] 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just define the function within the scope of the `ddply` call, and then use it. This might make the whole thing a lot easier to read.

```
df <- data.frame(id=rep(1:2,each=5),v1=c(1:10),v2=c(1:10))

df <- ddply(
  df,
  "id",
  mutate,
  sumv1v2={
    f <- function(pid,pv1,pv2) {
      if (pid[1]==1) pv1 + pv2 
      else 0
    }
    f(id,v1,v2)
  }
)
```